# How to change timezone for the ngx-daterangepicker-material daterangepicker in Angular 9?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, dayjs, ngx-daterangepicker-material

As per my requirement , I want to show the Hong Kong timezone even users from other timezone in ngx-daterangepicker-material. But date time picker shows locale time for Indian users . Here it needs to show the time of Hong Kong , not Indian time.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By use moment-timezone,
moment().tz('Your Timezone').subtract(29, 'day')